# Complex list of list of empty characters in a column in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a joined table which consists of list of list of characters.

```
q)t:([] a:`c`d; b:("";"fill"));
q)s:([] a:`b`c`c; b:("";"";""))
q)select from t lj select b by a from s
Output:
a b
---------
c ("";"") / This is the culprit want to replace it with null character
d "fill"
```

The output of join consists of a list of list of empty characters. 
I want to replace that with empty character.

```
Expected output:
     a b
    ---------
    c "" 
    d "fill"
```

Tried: Few Unsuccessful attempts

```
q)update b:?[null in b;raze b;b]from select from t lj select b by a from s 
q)update b:?["" in b;raze b;b]from select from t lj select b by a from s
```

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish the expected output you have provided, however your use case doesn't demonstrate what logic you want to implement. If you could elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish this would be helpful. E.g. what do you want to happen if c has two different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace a list of list of empty strings with empty string, you can try below query:

```
q) select from t lj  select (b;"")all""~/:b by a from s
```

Output:

```
a b     
--------
c ""    
d "fill"
```

**Explanation:**

Basically, empty strings list is coming from `group` command on the right table. So during the grouping stage, we can match if all the items in a grouped list (`b column values`) for particular `a` value are an empty string. And if they are just replacing them with a single empty string.

```
q) select (b;"")all""~/:b by a from s
```

```
a| b 
-| --
b| ""
c| ""
```

For `a` = c , `b` grouped values are ("";""). Lets break down the command:

```
q) b:("";"")
q) ""~/:b  / output 11b
q) all ""~/:b  / output 1b
q)(b;"") all ""~/:b  / output ""
```

The last command is list indexing. If the return from the previous command is 1b which means all items are empty strings, then return `""` else return actual b.

**Edit:**

Based on the discussion in the comment section of TerryLynch's answer, it looks like your requirement is:

- if all values of `b` list after grouping are empty strings then return a single empty string.
- if values of `b` are a mixture of empty strings and non-empty strings, then remove all empty strings.

For that, you could use the below query:

```
q) select from t lj select b:raze ("";b except enlist "") by a from s
```

But that would result in different types for different values in `b` column. An empty string will be 10h and all non-empty string list will be 0h.

For consistent type, can use below query which returns `enlist""` instead of `""` but that will not be an empty string:

```
q) select from t lj select b:{(c;enlist "")()~c:x except enlist ""}b by a from s
```

Comment: Added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to simply `raze` all the results of `b` together. Less `where` clauses in use and less match (`~`) operations.

```
q)update raze'/[b] from (t lj select b by a from s)
a b
--------
c ""
d "fill"
```

Here I've used over to account for more an unknown level of enlistment, as a precaustion, and then applied it to each row from the `lj`. For your case, an even faster solution would be

```
update raze each b from (t lj select b by a from s)
```

This will give different results than Rahuls answers

```
q)update raze each b from (t lj select b by a from s)
a b
--------
c "str"
d "fill"
q) select from t lj  select (b;"")all""~/:b by a from s
a b
------------
c ("";"str")
d "fill"
q)update raze each b from (t lj select b by a from s)
a b
--------
c "str"
d "fill"
```

Comment: It will raze other `b` values which might be the incorrect output.

Comment: I've responded in the original post to add the code block. Essentially it depends if you want a consistent type in your results.

Comment: That's true, it depends on the output. But I was talking about the cases where it will raze distinct values which are not null into one which might be incorrect. Try this table: s:([] a:\`b\`c\`c; b:("r";"tt";"yy"))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to fix the adverse outcome I think you need to decide what you want to do with the duplicate `c` rows in the `s` table. You're grouping by the `a` column but it has duplicates so how should it behave .... should it take the first value, should it take the last value? Should it append the two strings together? If you solve that then you avoid this problem, for example:

```
q)t lj select last b by a from s
a b
--------
c ""
d "fill"
```

Comment: This was the summary of the actual problem. Actual problem can have a row with a list of more than one string, a list of one string and one empty string, two or more empty strings. But the output required was if more than one string is empty in the output list then it should be replaced by single empty string.

Comment: So what output you want for cases where column 'b' will have a mixture of an empty string and actual values. Ex:  ("";"asd";"";"wewr")

Comment: Expected output in such case should be ("asd";"wewr").

Comment: @Utsav Then your final output column will have inconsistent types. Some entries will be a list of strings (type 0h) while some entries - the ones you're trying to force to be an empty string - will have type 10h. You can still work with it, but ideally you should try to keep the types consistent in a column

Comment: As terrylynch mentioned, you will get different types for values in `b` column.  To make type consistent, we can make query to return enlist "" which is different from an empty string. So it all depends on your requirement. I have also updated my answer based on your requirement that we discussed here.